# ubuntu halts itself in high cpu workload

Tags: cpu, crash

I have Core i3 M370 laptop.

When i do high cpu intensive tasks such as kernel compilation with *make -j4*, the system halts itself. It doesn't happen like instant crashing. It happens like "shutdown -h now"

When I do same thing in windows 8 with in ubuntu virtual machine(vmware), it doesn't happen.

Any ideas?

**Update :**

I managed to catch those message over ssh with *ssh root@192.168.1.15 'cat /proc/kmsg'*

> <2>[  732.301466] CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock
>   throttled (total events = 1) <2>[  732.301472] CPU3: Core temperature
>   above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1) <0>[ 
>   740.127491] thermal thermal_zone0: critical temperature reached(88 C),shutting down

apparently it does not do a good job at throttling. Is there any tuning options?

Comment: Does it just turn off? Isn't it overheating?

Comment: ubuntu is halting itself. If i am working in X, i see standard goodbye screen.

Comment: This is typical of hardware problems. Check with `dmesg` for notifications in that sense.

Comment: I don't think they are being logged in /var/log/dmesg during halting., I will try to get them with ssh connection.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Are the intake and/or exhaust vents blocked/dusty??